# How to create a shortcut on mac - so that arrow keys can also be triggered by "fn" + "j"/"i"/"k"/"l"

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

As title, Is there a way to create shortcut for Mac OS X, so that:

← can also be triggered by fn H

↓ can also be triggered by fn J

↑ can also be triggered by fn K

→ can also be triggered by fn L

Comment: Have a look at System Preferences: keyboard shortcuts

Comment: @SolarMike can change shortcut to mac default behaviors like flip page. But seems no way to create a new shortcut for arrow key?